# HTML вопрос: прокрутка содержимого

Tags: html, php, css

Вот
[сайт](http://pgups.16mb.com/)

Покрутите колесиком. Почему такая штука случилась? 
Исходник: [php файл и css файл](http://zalil.ru/32790290).

Answer (score 1):

Всё из-за `<div id='entry'>`, посмотри этот вариант:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>

<head>
  <title>Страница входа</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <meta name="description" content="PGUPS форум и файлообменник для студентов" />     <!-- Именно эта строка первой покажется в результатах поиска яндекса или рамблера, если они ещё нас найдут-->

  <meta name="keywords" content="PGUPS, ПГУПС, форум, Санкт-Петербург, Студенты, файлы." /> <!-- ключевые слова для поисковиков. -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleIndex.css">
</head>

<body>

<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- <font class="text1">Вход:</font><br> Красный текст -->
            <p>
                <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
                <input class="inup" type="text" onblur="if (value == '') {value='E-mail'}" onfocus="if (value == 'E-mail') {value =''}" value="E-mail" name="email">
<br><br>
                <label for="pass">Пароль:</label>
                <input class="inup" type="password" onblur="if (value == '') {value='Пароль'}" onfocus="if (value == 'Пароль') {value =''}" value="Пароль" name="pass">
<br><br>

                <input type="submit" class='btn' value="Войти" style="margin-left: 80px;" onclick='window.location="login.php"'>
                <input type=button class='btn' value=' Регистрация ' onclick='window.location="request.html"'>
<br></p>
</form>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

А все потому что `background-attachment: fixed`. Уберите бяку и поставьте `background-position: 50% 0`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло))